# Possible to re-select data table columns after formatting?

Tags: r, datatable

I am using `DT::datatable` to format some a table. Is it possible to select only certain columns after formatting has been applied. For example:

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  datatable(options = list(dom = "l"))
```

If I wanted to keep this formatting (i.e., only keeping the page-length option), but only see `mpg` and `cyl` is there anyway to filter *after* the formatting has been applied, something like:

```
mtcars %>% 
  datatable(options = list(dom = "l")) %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl)
```

I want to let users dynamically select which columns they want to show and which ones they want to hide. As such, I'd prefer to apply custom table styles to the whole table at the outset, then just keep those columns that the user selects.

Comment: I want to let users dynamically select which columns they want to show and which ones they want to hide. As such, I'd prefer to apply custom table styles to the whole table at the outset, then just keep those columns that the user selects.

Comment: I think you can use `?dataTableProxy` and the `?selectColumns` functions for this. I've never done it before, but this looks like a good place to start](https://thatdatatho.com/r-shiny-data-table-proxy-replace-data/).